# even after giving all permissions to site i am getting the following error while hosting express js site using iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis, express, iisnode

Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, realpath 'D:\Inetpub\vhosts\homesfy.in\staging.homesfy.in\express\server.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1574:18)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:167:25)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:210:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)`

Comment: can anybody please help me the correct way to do it ?. default site that comes with iisnode installation is working fine

Comment: I found an alternate way : run the node application as a service using nssm and use url rewriting (reverse proxy)for port forwarding .

Comment: http://qr.ae/1DIOLS